# The method of dotz .z.u user reassignment

Tags: kdb

Just wondering why does the 3rd method works, if the first ones don't?:

```
.z.u:`admin          // silently doesn't work (.z.u unchanged)
`.[`.z.u]:`admin     // 'assign
@[`.;`.z.u;:;`admin] // ok!
```

It look like a some kind of textual-override, after

```
delete .z.u from `.
```

`.z.u` gets back to normal. So may be q detects these overrides in the first two cases and politely asks us not doing so..

The original problem was: why the heck this:

```
h{.z.w{.z.u},`},`
```

returns empty? and makes innocent process looking bad to others, as it's `.z.u` became empty being called on `.z.w`. But it is the same process - nothing changed.. do I need to put this fancy line on every process to overcome the issue?:

```
@[`.;`.z.u;:;.z.u]
```

or is it more ideologically to use:

```
0[`.z.u]
```

to get the process user?

Weird that for `.z.h` it is the different behavior (as expected). Why don't remove `.z.h` also :)?

Comment: The null return is documented as intentional https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zu-user-id `h({.z.w".z.u"};::)    / client side returns null symbol`

Comment: Safest way to get process user in my experience is to always use `0".z.u"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it's not strictly true that you're overwriting .z.u in this case.

What you're saying with `` @[`.;`.z.u;:;`admin] `` is "within the root namespace create a new variable called .z.u". And q goes and does exactly this: it creates a new variable called `.z.u`. This variable exists in just the same way as a variable like, say,  `a:1` or `var:123`.

From q's perspective this variable doesn't exist in the .z namespace, it exists in the root namespace.
We can see that the original `.z.u` remains unaltered by, say, checking it's value from another namespace:

```
q)@[`.;`.z.u;:;`admin]
`.
q).z.u
`admin
q)\d .test       ^
q.test).z.u
`HehirS
```

Although I would not advise this you can also do this trick with other names that would usually be unassignable e.g.:

```
q)@[`.;`123;:;"hi"]
`.
q)123
123
q)value`123
"hi"
```

You can also try different .z variables but your millage will vary:

```
// server process
q)\p 9876
q)@[`.;`.z.pg;:;{break}]
`.
q).z.pg
{break}

// client process
q)h:hopen`::9876
q)h"2+2"
4
```

So in this case while it looks like .z.pg has been reassigned to 'break when a sync message is received we can see the default behaviour of .z.pg is still preserved.

Also as a side note:

```
`.[`.z.u]:`admin
```

This will not work for any variable. You're trying to assign a value to the result of `` `.[`.z.u] `` which doesn't make sense to the interpreter.